# Gulp not compiling css

Tags: sass, gulp

I have a problem with my gulpfile. When i execute task its works but not compiling any css files.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    min = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    tar = require('gulp-tar'),
    gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    util = require('gulp-util');


var PATH_JS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/js/',
    PATH_CSS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/src/scss/',
    PATH_CSS_DIST = 'src/main/webapp/styles/';



gulp.task('default', function(){

});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){

});


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src(PATH_CSS_SRC + 'main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(min({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_CSS_DIST));
});
```

What did i do wrong ? any advice ?

Comment: In my gulpfile I at first do `.pipe(concat('app.css'))` and then `.pipe(sass(...))`. Try to swap these two lines. And do you run `gulp sass` task?

Comment: Yes in my cmd `gulp sass`

Comment: Wow its actually works thank you so much i changed lines :) !!!

Comment: What is concat doing for you anyway?  You have one file in your pipeline.  Even if main.scss imports other sass files they are inlined into main.scss and the sass pipe will output main.css.  If you want to change that filename just do a gulp-rename pipe, not a concat.  It may be that gulp is getting confused by a one file concat.  Keep your original order and replace the concat pipe with a rename pipe and see if it works, then you would know if the strange concat is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to swap between 2 lines in the last gulp task that you have wrotten. Let´s put *.pipe(concat('app.css'))* before *.pipe(sass(...))*

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    min = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    tar = require('gulp-tar'),
    gzip = require('gulp-gzip'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    util = require('gulp-util');


var PATH_JS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/js/',
    PATH_CSS_SRC = 'src/main/webapp/frontend/src/scss/',
    PATH_CSS_DIST = 'src/main/webapp/styles/';



gulp.task('default', function(){

});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){

});


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src(PATH_CSS_SRC + 'main.scss')
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(min({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_CSS_DIST));
});
```